# Scripts issue in ie7 in the JSON response

Tags: jquery, json

I have a script starting with the comment notaiton in the JSON response. This throws an syntax error in ie7 on runscirpts @ eval(e.text); //run the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function(){                  
    //utils.normalizeColumnHeight($('.aboutus-filter-wrapper, .aboutdesc_wrapper,.right_box_wrapper'));
});
// --></script>
```

Iam executing the scripts using runscripts for ie. here is ths code

```
 runScripts1: function(e) {
    if (e.nodeType != 1) return false; //if it's not an element node, return

    if (e.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'script') {
        //alert(e.text);
        eval(e.text); //run the script
    }
    else {
        var n = e.firstChild;
        while ( n ) {
            if ( n.nodeType == 1 ) forrester.runScripts1(n); //if it's an element node, recurse
            n = n.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    return true;
},
```

how to avoid the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an invalid commenting construct in the Javascript snippet, furthermore, the closing of the invalid comment context is appropriately commented out while the starting point is present.

That is,

- the `<!-- comment -->` construct is valid in HTML
- the `//comment` or `/* comment */` constructs are valid in Javascript
- but they aren't interchangeable

Browsers might not like this at all.

If you're getting this script as a response from a call somewhere, then I would try first looking at source: do you have control of the output?

If so, change it to remove invalid stuff. If you *are* getting this code from a service call / external source, I'd recommend not doing so at all. That, though, is perhaps a topic for another question.